# VBA - Put copied Items into a Table/Borders

Tags: excel, vba

With a lot of help by this forum this code was generated.The Advancedfilter works perfectly but the frame/table around the copied items is not working properly.

But unfortunately its not working that the items are withtin Borders. Just always the three first rows.
Does anyone know why?

```
Sub Unique_Values_Worksheet_Variables()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("export")
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    sws.Range("F:F").AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=dws.Range("A:A"), _
        Unique:=True
              
 dws.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

    
End Sub
```

Comment: Is row 4 blank ?

Comment: @CDP1802 no..the copied values after row 3 are just not with borders

Comment: Does your export sheet have a hidden row 4. Your code works fine for my simple test case so I suspect it's in the data.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the range explicitly using `End(xlup)`

```vb
Sub Unique_Values_Worksheet_Variables()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("export")
    Dim dws As Worksheet, rng As Range

    Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    sws.Range("F:F").AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=dws.Range("A:A"), _
        Unique:=True
              
    dws.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Set rng = dws.Range("A1", dws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    
    rng.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    With rng.Borders()
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: works perfectly! Thanks a lot "End(xlUp)...i have to check